# How can I make my Samsung Galaxy S9+ install unsigned applications?

Tags: rooting, apk

I have root on my phone, and also Lucky Patcher patched the signature verification stuff (both of them). I have rooted my Galaxy with Magisk and Odin (using PC). I can't patch "dalvik-cache" whatever that means, and I have a suspicion that that is why my unsigned apks install, but crash straight after opening. It's not the app, as I can use them perfectly well on an emulator. Does anyone know how to get past this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Android can not install unsigned apps/APKs, the APK signature is always checked when you install it. The only way would be to manipulate an already installed app. Upon installation the APK file is saved, some files extracted and the DEX files are pre-compiled using dex2oat on modern devices using ART runtime. Those extracted files and the APK itself can be modified but that isn't that simple. I assume that is Lucky Patcher is trying to do and fails.

Comment: @Robert Maybe some signature could be updated in some apk manifest?

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica You can of course re-sign an APK file with a self-generated key pair. But then Android would not allow to install this app as an update of an already existing app because the keys do not match. On a rooted device it may be possible to change the files where Android saves the info which installed app is signed by what key, but I never did this before and don't know how complicated such a modification would be.

Answer (score -2):

Check whether apps can support your android OS version.

You can turn on Allow installation of app from unknown sources. Go to setting / security / turn on Unknown sources option.

Comment: "Allow installation of app from unknown sources" -- this wouldn't make a difference. Unsigned apps cannot be installed. See https://source.android.com/security/apksigning